# .swf file duration (length)

Tags: c#, flash

I have a problem getting .swf files time duration.
I tried by calling ffmped via cmd in C# and it worked for other video files (.avi, .mp4, .mov etc.), but not for .swf.
(Also, when I open the .swf file in Media Player Classic and when I go to properties, it says the length is 00:00:00, but it plays.)

Comment: SWF File's could be Infite one ,and that can be configured before it get's compiled so SWF File's are not used like a Video Files they are more like Interactive Multimedia File's ,because you can find ActionScript behind them ,another video ect. So not always they have a specific duration .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWF is a container format. What you're looking for is the length of the `*.flv` file. That is the actual encoded video. What happens is the SWF file has an internal reference to the FLV file, and then loads / streams *that* file. AFAIK, ffmpeg should be able to get the length of an FLV file.

Comment: Ffmpeg gives me the duration of .flv files. But do you mean that in the command fo ffmpeg in cmd I should write video1.flv instead of video1.swf? Or that I should first convert the .swf to .flv?

Comment: swf and flv are two completely different file formats. To use an analogy, the swf file would be the television, while the flv would be the actual program being watched. The only time you need the swf file is to actually view the flv video in the browser.